# How does Shadow of Moil interact with Beholder rays?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light

Shadow of Moil makes the caster heavily obscured. How does this condition interact with save based attacks?

For instance, would a warlock with this buff be un-targetable by a beholders eye ray or a similar ability requiring a saving throw?

Comment: Did you read the rules for “heavily obscured”? The answer seems quite obvious to me from a brief review of those rules, but I may be missing something here. Can you give more details about what is confusing you here?

Comment: Read the rules, I legit I'm not sure, would not have asked the question otherwise. Comment like it seems obvious is not helpful to me. Is it obvious that they are targetable? Or is it obvious that they are not targetable? Can already see this question is getting downvotes poured on it but I do need to know the answer

Comment: I was just wondering if there were any more details about your own investigation you could include here, our [how to ask a good question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) suggests including your own research in the question.

Comment: No I think my issue was that i was just a bit incredulous at the power of Moil. However, it's good... Basically like Greater Invisibility. As far as asking a good question I just wanted to ask the question straight up without giving any bias. I believe that a question like that is legit... Though my idea of what's a good question may be at odds with yours. Thanks for the concise answer.

Comment: Generally the more details you can include, the better. We often see that when a user includes some of their own research in the question, it reveals to readers exactly where the hang up is, when it wasn’t clear what that hang up was without those details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### A beholder must be able to see its target, which “heavily obscured” prevents.

The beholder’s *Eye Rays* ability says:

> choosing one to three targets it can *see*

Heavily obscured says:

> A heavily obscured area--such as darkness, opaque fog, or dense foliage--*blocks vision entirely*. A creature effectively suffers from the blinded condition when trying to see something in that area.

Since the beholder can’t see a heavily obscured creature, it cannot target it with its Eye Rays. A creature under the effect of *shadow of moil* cannot be targeted by any ability or feature that requires the target to be seen, because *shadow of moil* says:

> Flame-like shadows wreathe your body until the spell ends, causing you to become heavily obscured to others.

It should be noted that this applies to your allies as well; while under *shadow of moil*, you cannot be targeted by the cleric’s *healing word*.

Comment: It could be a good idea to also mention that other effects interact differently. The OP specified the Beholder in the title, but in the text of the question it seems to just be an example of "save based attacks". For example, Shadow of Moil would not protect against a dragon's breath weapon.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Good point, I’ll work something in.